# Global Asymptotic Stability of a System

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-analysis, lyapunov-functions

I have  a system $V(x)$, in $R^2$, and I've calculated that

$V(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ not equal to zero and that $V(0,0) = 0$

I've also calculated that $V'(x) \leq 0$

Since $V'(x)$ is NSD and not ND I have deduced that the system is globally asymptotically stable.

Is there any flaw in my analysis? Or is it correct?

(I've also calculated that as |V(x)| goes to infinity as ||x|| goes to infinity)

My system is

$x' = -y-x^3$

$y' = x^5$

My Lyapunov function is $V(x) = x^6+3y^2$. I'm trying to see if it's globally asymptotically stable or not but I'm not sure if my answer is correct.

Comment: In your original question (before formatting) it was $V(x) >= 0$. Are you sure you mean $V(x) \rightarrow 0$ and not $V(x) \geq 0$ (same for $V' \leq 0$)? If that is the case, there is still the flaw that you need $V(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$, not only $V(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: I meant that V(x) is greater than zero for all x when x isn't zero. V'(x) is less than zero for all x, not equal zero and equals zero for x = 0

Comment: In general you cannot say anything about the stability of the system if your Lyapunov function candidate does not satisfy the conditions. Maybe there is another function out there that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: My Lyapunov function satisfies the conditions needed.

Comment: @AbdulazizBoalbanat Then you should probably edit your question to reflect that, at the moment it is very confusing. And no, your Lyapunov function does not satisfy the needed conditions to conclude anything about asymptotic stability.

Comment: My system is x' = -y-x^3 , y' = x^5. & My Lyapunov function is V(x) = x^6+3y^2. I'm trying to see if it's globally asymptotically stable or not but I'm not sure of my answer. I'm getting that it is.

Comment: @AbdulazizBoalbanat You are getting it is what? Asymptotically stable? In your question you said it is not. Please edit your question and state clearly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You have the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -x^3 - y \\
\dot{y} &= x^5
\end{align}
$$

And the Lyapunov function

$$
\begin{align}
V(x) &= x^6 + 3 y^2 \\
\dot{V}(x) &= -6 x^8
\end{align}
$$

So your Lyapunov function is positive definite (PD), means it is $V(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$, not $\geq$ like you wrote in the question. This is important because otherwise it would be only positive semi definite (and therefore not valid).

The derivative $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$ for $x \neq 0$, negative semi definite (NSD) so the trajectories are bounded but we don't know yet if the system is also asymptotically stable.

We can use LaSalle for it: $\dot{V}(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$ but then $\dot{x} = -y$. If $y \neq 0$ you can't keep $\dot{V}(x) = 0$.

Conclusion: The system is globally asymptotically stable.

In general if we only know $V(x)$ is PD and $\dot{V}(x)$ is NSD then we don't know if the system is asymptotically stable without more investigation (like LaSalle).